# c++ operator overloading logical opertors

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, logical-operators

Hi I was wondering how I could tackle this problem,

I need to overload +, - and * operators but need to replace them with Logical operators for example;

"+" should use OR

0+0 = 0 , 0+1 = 1, 1+1 = 1 ,1+0 = 1

would i have to place in the overload some sort of if statment?

Any help on how i could do this?

Thanks

They will being using binary as the data type, two matrices with binary as their data

Comment: Should these functions operate on integers? What should the behaviour be for non 0,1 inputs?

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Don’t give existing operators unexpected new semantics (unless you’re the author of a Boost library and have a damn good reason), this doesn’t help, on the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for an `if` statement, you just need to return the result of `&&` and `||`.

```
struct A
{
   bool val;
   bool operator + (const A& other) { return val || other.val; }
   bool operator * (const A& other) { return val && other.val; }
};
```

Note that you can't overload operators for built-in types. At least one of the arguments **must** be user-defined.

Comment: I'd also like an explanation please.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to overload those operators for integers, or any other built-in types, do you? Because it's impossible. If you have your own class which *contains* a boolean or integer value then the logic goes something like this:

```
bool operator + (const MyClass& m1, const MyClass& m2) 
{
     return m1.GetMyBooleanMember() || m2.GetMyBooleanMember();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overloading operator+(int, int) is not possible, however you can create a new type that wraps an int and has the behavior you want...

```
struct BoolInt
{
   int i;
};

BoolInt operator+(BoolInt x, BoolInt y) { return { x.i || y.i }; }
BoolInt operator*(BoolInt x, BoolInt y) { return { x.i && y.i }; }
BoolInt operator-(BoolInt x, BoolInt y) { return { x.i || !y.i }; } // guessing
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but just impossible. Naming the new class Int isn't a very good idea either.

Comment: "Overloading operator+(int, int) is not a good idea." not only is it not a good idea, it's also impossible.